# Rails 5 - Run PDFtk on local machine - Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdftk

I'm trying to run PDFtk in my Rails app on my local machine and running into a permission denied error when the app tries to access the executable. I have downloaded the PDFtk files into:

```
/Users/pdftk/bin/pdftk
/Users/pdftk/lib/libgcj.so.12
```

I have the following local ENV variables:

```
PDFTK_PATH=/Users/me/pdftk/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/me/pdftk/lib
```

But when I attempt to create a new PDF using:

```
PdfForms.new(ENV['PDFTK_PATH'])
```

I get a

> Errno::EACCES

error stating

> Permission denied - /Users/me/pdftk/bin

I have attempted to set permissions on the directories and executable via chmod to no avail. The pdftk executable permissions are curretly:

```
-rwxrw-rw-@ 1 me  otheruser  3046752 Dec 26 22:38 pdftk
```

I followed [this post](http://derekbarber.ca/blog/2014/11/20/using-pdftk-with-rails-on-heroku/) to get this all working and it works perfectly fine on Heroku, just not locally.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn’t put the pdftk library in your app’s vendor directory locally?

Comment: @John-MichaelL'Allier It is there as well. I get the same error if I set the PDFTK_PATH to that location.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change the path to `PDFTK_PATH = /app/vendor/pdftk/bin/pdftk` (link directly to the pdftk executable, not the bin it's in). Found in a comment on [this thread](http://derekbarber.ca/blog/2014/11/20/using-pdftk-with-rails-on-heroku/).

Comment: That's the post I used to get it set up. Using that path I get "Could not find an executable ["/app/vendor/pdftk/bin/pdftk"] on your path" despite it being there.